# Webpack Babel build fails when importing files outside entry path

Tags: node.js, webpack, babeljs, webpack-4, babel-loader

I have this project that i'm already using webpack + babel to build. I've hit a wall since what i want to do is share some constants between my node (server) and my react app (front-end).
My project structure is this

```
- app
- internals
  - webpack
    - different webpack configs (node, react-dev, react-production etc)
- server
- shared
- .babelrc
```

I've put some "constants" files into the shared folder that I use both from my app and from my server.
When I try to build my server I get this

```
ERROR in ./shared/reports.constants.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
TypeError: Cannot read property 'code' of null
at transpile (C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\XXX\XXX\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:70:21)
at Object.module.exports (C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\XXX\XXX\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js
:173:20)
```

Below is my webpack config file. Any ideas what might be wrong ?

```
{
    mode: 'production',
    target: 'node',
    externals: nodeExternals(),
    entry: {
        server: [path.join(process.cwd(), 'server/index.js')],
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        path: path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'build'),
        // sourceMapFilename: '[name].js.map',
    },
    devtool: 'hidden-source-map',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(
                  { fallback: 'style-loader', use: { loader: 'css-loader', options: { minimize: true } } }),
            },
            { test: /\.jpg$/, use: [{ loader: 'file-loader', options: { name: '/images/[name].[ext]' } }] },
            { test: /\.md$/, use: [{ loader: 'markdown-with-front-matter-loader' }] },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: [/node_modules/],
                include: [/server/, /shared/],
                use: [
                    'babel-loader',
                    {
                        loader: 'webpack-preprocessor-loader',
                        options: {
                            debug: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
                            directives: {
                                secret: false,
                            },
                            params: {
                                ENV: process.env.NODE_ENV,
                                DEBUG: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
                                PRODUCTION: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
                                ENVIRONMENT: process.env.ENVIRONMENT,
                            },
                            verbose: false,
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
plugins
etc
}
```

.babelrc file

```
{
  "presets": [
     "@babel/preset-env"
   ],
   "plugins": [
       "react-hot-loader/babel",
       "@babel/transform-runtime",
       "transform-html-import-to-string"
   ]
}
```

I've added the `/shared/` to the includes rules.

Thank you in advance

Comment: It's too hard to find out what is wrong here based on what you have given so it's best if you provide minimal reproducible repo.

Comment: What folder is your `.babelrc` in? If it's not in a parent directory of all of your code, then it's not going to work. You probably want to use a `babel.config.js` instead.

Comment: Its in the root dir but the webpack config is nested in folders. What's the advantages of using babel.config.js instead of babelrc ?

Comment: But there is only 1 package.json file. Just different webpack config for app/server

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I already had a babel.config.js + the babelrc. All I had to do was go into the babel.config.js and add the shared folder to be included in the env => production.

Thank you for your time